# What's a good pattern for writing a Module and Class that augments Middleman?

Tags: middleman

I'm using Middleman 3.4.0 and in customizing my project I have some methods that are becoming too extensive for keeping them as helpers in `config.rb`. I'd like to write either a Module or Class and mix these back in as helpers with the ability to model the objects I need to work with. Is there a pattern for writing this as a Middleman extension somewhere that I can start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `middleman extension <extension name>` command, which gives you a good boilerplate, [see here.](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/)

Comment: Is this part of 3x, 4x or both? Not immediately clear on that from the documentation.

Comment: Check and see. I think 3 has it too.